# How do I prompt for Password in awk?

Tags: awk

I am trying to prompt for password if the password is passed as command line argument in (g)awk. The reason for this is of course you do not want the password in cleartext in logs.

I am working with an awk script, so I will do this from awk and save the password in an awk variable. I know it is possible to use the "read" function from bash, but this is also creating a separate subprocess making things very cumbersome to deal with.

Anyone who knows if built in support for this exists in awk?

BR
Patrik

Comment: my 2¢, `awk` is not the right tool for whatever usecase you are developing.

Comment: @Inian You may be right, but it have been like this for 18 years and there is a lot of advanced functionality in the product. We could probably try to rewrite if if we had 20000 or so hours to spare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `stty` to disable the terminal output when typing the password:

```
function getpass() {
    printf "password:";
    "stty -echo" | getline;
    getline pwd < "/dev/stdin";
    printf "\n";
    "stty echo" | getline;
    return pwd;
}

BEGIN {
    if(!pwd) {
        pwd = getpass();
    }   
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

We'll always have `/dev/stdin`:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    password="foo"
    printf "Enter password: "
    while((getline line < "/dev/stdin") > 0 && line!=password) {
        printf "Wrong password.\n\nEnter password: "
    }
    if(line==password)                                            # in case of ^D
        print "Correct password was " line
    else                                                          # handles ^D
        exit
}'
```

A sample login session:

```
Enter password: asd
Wrong password.

Enter password: foo
Correct password was foo
```

Comment: This will of course solve the problem of not logging the password, but I actually prefers the other answer, so the password is silent. The basic principle I was after were to imitate the behavior of linux externally.